# Sorting and placing matched values on top

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB and Node.js to display a record set in a page. I have got as far as displaying them on the page alphabetically, but I would like to display one row (the "default" row) at the top, and all the others alphabetically beneath it.

I know, I know, Mongo is definitely not SQL, but in SQL I would have done something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM themes
ORDER BY name != "Default", name ASC;
```

or perhaps even

```
SELECT * FROM themes WHERE name  = "Default"
UNION
SELECT * FROM themes WHERE name != "Default" ORDER BY name ASC;
```

I have tried a few variations of Mongo's sorting options, such as

```
"$orderby": {'name': {'$eq': 'Default'}, 'name': 1}}
```

but without any luck so far. I have been searching a lot for approaches to this problem but I haven't found anything. I am new to Mongo but perhaps I'm going about this all wrong.

My basic code at the moment:

```
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('themes');

collection.find({"$query": {}, "$orderby": {'name': 1}}, function(e, results) {
    res.render('themes-saved', {
        title: 'Themes',
        section: 'themes',
        page: 'saved',
        themes: results
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that in MongoDB, as sorting must be on a specific value already present in a field of your document. What you "can" do is [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) a "weighting" to the record(s) matching your condition. As in:

```js
collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": {
            "each": 1,
            "field": 1,
            "youWant": 1,
            "name": 1,
            "weight": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$name", "Default" ] },
                    10,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }},
        { "$sort": { "weight": -1, "name": 1 } }
    ],
    function(err,results) {

    }
);
```

So you logically inspect the field you want to match a value in ( or other logic ) and then assign a value to that field, and a lower score or `0` to those that do not match.

When you then `$sort` on that "weighting" first in order ( decending from highest in this case ) so that those values are listed before others with a lower weighting.